# how to return almost similar object without repeating the entire object again

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript object something like below:

```
something = {
        a: 1,
        b: 2,
        c: 3,
    }
```

In my “`if`” condition, I want to return the above object but in my “`else`” condition, I want to return the same object but without the third property.

```
c: 3
```

Is there a way I can do that without repeating  or writing the object again in the else condition and excluding the third property (c:3)
Hope I made the question clear. The reason I am doing this is because my `if` condition is very big and I don't want to write it again in the `else` block since it will be repeating the entire `if` logic but with one less property. Please let me know If I was unable to explain my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the base object without `c`, then add the `c` property in the `if`:

```
const base = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
};
if (cond) {
  return { ...base, c: 3 };
} else {
  return base;
}
```

Another option, by using `&&` to conditionally spread in the `c` property:

```
return {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  ...(cond && { c: 3 })
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use delete operator also as an alternative.

```
const something = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
};
if (condition) {
  return something;
} else {
  delete something.c;
  return something;
}
```